# Javascript Windows store app and non-ascii filename uploads

Tags: javascript, file-upload, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to upload a file to an Apache server with a Windows Store App. Ascii file names work fine, but any other foreign characters will not work, Apache is throwing a 400.

The files are being uploaded the standard Windows store way with Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundUploader, and then creating a BackgroundTransferContentPart from the file.

```
  var uploader = new Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundUploader();
  var part = new Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundTransferContentPart('file',  file.name);
  part.setFile(file);
  var parts = [ part ];
  uploader.createUploadAsync(url, parts).then(callback)
```

Doing an upload in javascript with an ajax request works fine with non-ascii filenames.
Has anyone encountered this in the windows apps?

Edit: I got fiddler working and here is part of the body of the request:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename*=utf-8''%C3%BCf.txt
```

It's sending a malformed request so thats why apache rejects it.  The "filename" part is malformed, it should just be something like filename="üf.txt"

Comment: I think that problem in the filename encoding. It should be utf-8 and it should be set to utf-8 somewhere in post data and also file name should be in utf-8 encoding.

Comment: I managed to get fiddler working with the store app and edited the question

Comment: http headers are always ascii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the filename*=utf-8'' is actually a standard: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.3

So for some reason there's a bug in the backend of not reading this correctly